# How to customize the form of SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

For example I would like to do this.

A. Show map instead of latitude and altitude property.

B. Show thumbnails of pictures instead of select box for pictures.

I can do this kind of things for list screen like this below.

```
public function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('id')

        ->add('map',null,array('template' => 'AcmeAdminBundle:MyTemplate:list_map.html.twig',
                'property_path' => false
        ))
```

After overriding the template and then it is possible to show the map or do some complex things in my original list_map.html.twig

Now I want to try the same thing with Form though,'FormMapper' doesn't have 'template' option.

So, I override the  form_admin_fields.html.twig and edit someplaces but it doesn't change the each objects of form.

Even I delete all of code in form_admin_fields.html.twig. (makes the blank file)

It just changes the layout of form.

I would like to customize each text box or select box of form.

Where should I start to customize form page in SonataAdminBundle??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create custom field type for this, like [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html)

Comment: HI @Andrey Kazmerchuk, thank you for your advice, I understood how to make custom field. However I still have some difficulties to use custom fields in Sonat Admin Bundle. But your advice makes me progress. thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. FormMapper in Sonata Admin bundle works like usual Symfony Form, so my link should be enough. You just create custom field type and template for it, and register it like service. After that it can be easily used in FormMapper.